# how to sort a list in a while loop

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, if-statement

I want to write a program which reads numbers continuously from the user *(one at a time)*, until the user enters "0"

and then the program returns the smallest number in that inputs. I am having trouble sorting out.

This is my code so far:

```
while True:
    number = []
    number = input("Please enter a number ")

    if number == "0":
       break
    
    number.sort()
    x = number[0]
return x
```

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite your number at each step, this cannot work. You should keep track of the min value instead:

```
min_value = None
while True:
    number = int(input("Please enter a number ")) # no type check here
    if number == 0:
        break

    if number is None or number < min_value:
        min_value = number

print(min_value)
```

Comment: Would be more intuitive to set `min_value = float('inf')`   Then later just do comparison as:  `min_value = min(number, min_value)` ?  Yours works fine, just suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of your entered numbers *appending* them and then finding the minimum value using the `numpy` module. For example:

```
import numpy as np

 while True:
     number_list = []
     number = input("Please enter a number ")
     number_list.append(number)

     if number == "0":
     break

 number_array = np.array(number_list)
 minval = np.min(number_array[np.nonzero(number_array)])
```

So that you can find the minimum value of the array, excluding the "0" you entered at the end.